# How to setup a Tkinter button to erase once clicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

As the title says, I want to erase a button when it is clicked. I have tried many different styles and this one seemed to be the simplest, but I keep getting the error:

```
line 34, in incorrect
    button2.Button.destroy()
NameError: name 'button2' is not defined
```

and when trying a different method as shown below, this one:

```
NameError: name 'button2' is not defined
```

When trying to define it in the beginning I would receive this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'button2' referenced before assignment
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**My code:**

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(object):
     def __init__(self):
          self.root = Tk()
          self.root.configure(bg="darkorchid1", padx=10, pady=10)
          self.root.title("WELCOME TO THIS PROGRAM)")

    self.username = "Bob"

    program = Label(self.root, text="MY PROGRAM", bg="lightgrey", fg="darkorchid1")
    program.pack()

    label0 = Label(self.root, text="ENTER USERNAME:", bg="purple", fg="white", height=5, width=50)
    label0.pack()

    self.entry = Entry(self.root, width=25)
    self.entry.configure(fg= "white",bg="grey20")
    self.entry.pack()

    button = Button(self.root, text="SUBMIT", highlightbackground="green", width=48, command=self.correct)
    button.pack()

def correct(self):
    username = self.entry.get()
    if username == self.username:
        button1 = Button(self.root, text='LOGIN', highlightbackground="green", width=28, command=self.root.destroy)
        button1.pack()
    elif username != self.username:
       button2 = Button(self.root, text="INCORRECT- CLICK TO DIMISS THIS MESSAGE", highlightbackground="red", width=48, command=self.incorrect)
       button2.pack()

def incorrect(self):
    button2.destroy() 



app=Application()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your `button`-variables within a class or just pass them to your functions. You got problems because of your `button2` is out of scope!

Try this instead:

```
   def correct(self):
        username = self.entry.get()
        if username == self.username:
            self.button1 = Button(self.root, text='LOGIN', highlightbackground="green",
                                  width=28, command=self.root.destroy)
            self.button1.pack()
        elif username != self.username:
            self.button2 = Button(self.root,
                                  text="INCORRECT- CLICK TO DIMISS THIS MESSAGE",
                                  highlightbackground="red", width=48,
                                  command=self.incorrect)
            self.button2.pack()

    def incorrect(self):
        self.button2.destroy()
```

Comment: The `elif username != self.username:` is redundant since the preceding conditional expression is its **exact** opposite—in which case `else:` is all that's needed. Seems like that's just commonsense...

Comment: @martineau, let's leave it to OP's conscience. Thanks for ironic and  
obvious addition. (:

Comment: Yes I think martineau is correct. I was just trying to make it as specific as possible to eliminate any potential mistakes. And thank you SO much @CommonSense. I'm still really new to this so that was really helpful. I really appreciate it. BTW do you know how to connect the enter key to the initial submit button. All the answers I have found do not seem to work. 

self.button = Button(self.root, text="SUBMIT", highlightbackground="green", width=48, command=self.correct)
        self.button.pack()
        self.button.bind("<Return>", command=self.correct)
What do you think would be best?

Comment: @gmonz , try to bind without "command" key, this will work. And i suggest binding to your entry widget!

Comment: @CommonSense, I tried self.button.bind("<Return>", self.correct), self.button.bind_all("<Return>", self.correct), self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.correct), self.entry.bind_all("<Return>", self.correct). I tried connecting to self.root and self.init and self.__init__ as well in addition to the bind_all idea as well. Any other ideas? I get this error with your idea:Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: correct() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @gmonz, ha ha, it's a old catch for thoose who new to tkinter. On events `tk` pass another one argument(event) to your function, to deal with it just declare it like `def correct(self, event=None):` See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842770/python-function-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given-how). And I suggest you [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) site too (many of your future questions are presented).

Comment: Wow you are legit! Haha thank you so much it worked! I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: @CommonSense, the Incorrect-Dimiss button erases on click, but if I enter more than one incorrect user name, more of them pop up unless clicked. The issue is that I can only click one to erase it. The rest are either unclickable or clickable but do nothing. (1)How can I make it to where I can click on each of them if there are say 10 failed attempts and they all go away when clicked instead of only being able to make one go away on click?(2)Also is there a max login attempts code that ends the program? And last question- (3)how do you restart the program from the beginning without it closing?

Comment: @gmonz, feel free to ask this as new question. This is a comment section.